# TCP client in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server written in python and clients in bash.

Client sends data like this

```
cat file > /dev/tcp/ip/port
```

and python server sends the response

```
clientsocket.send('some response')
```

I can send my data to server, it works fine but when server tries to send response my bash script blocks itself. I tried to use descriptors like below:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/ip/port
cat file >&3

RESPOND=`cat <&3`
echo $RESPOND
```

but it does not work (blocks itself)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cat` will probably wait for the socket to be closed.  I suggest reading line by line using `read` instead, if you really think that bash is the best language to write a TCP client.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, could you give an example?

Comment: Like `read x <&3`, and then make sure that you print one message per line on the server side.  It would be kind of a mediocre protocol, but with the client being written in bash, you will be somewhat limited anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `netcat` or `nc` instead. You can set up a server to listen on port 1234 with

```
command=$(netcat -l 1234)
```

and you can transmit a message to that host on that port with

```
echo "message" | nc <host> 1234
```

or send a file with

```
nc <host> 1234 < someFile.txt
```

Comment: As I said, I have server in python

Comment: The point isn't to replace the server, it is to try and test it out using a well-known client that works - i.e. `netcat`

Comment: @Sheppard25 I think that this link can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers